# Rotuing between HTTP service in camel

Tags: rest, cxf, apache-camel

I want to route output of one http rest sevice to another through camel. Can someone help me how to do that?

The requirement is to call one httpURL - 
    `http://someserver/path/service1`
and transfer its output to another httpURL -         `http://someserver/path/service2`
 and finally display output of this service2 to user.

So can anybody help me how to do that or any link doing same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this.
      
        http://someserver:8080/path/service1?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
        http://someserver:8090/path/service2?bridgeEndpoint=true?throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>

Note that you specified the same server "someserver", but you may want to specify another server or port where the "true" service is located, depending on where it is hosted. I added port numbers in the example.

(Example from [here](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-camel-as-a-http-proxy-between-a-client-and-server.html))